# BigQuery How to update multiple numeric columns by the same rule?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, sql-update

Is there any way to update multiple numeric columns by the same rules?

Before:

[image]

After:
Numeric columns multiple 10

[image]

My Query:

```
select id, (sales*10) as sales, (spend*10) as spend, product
from table
```

But I have many columns in one table, is there any other simple way to update the data?

Comment: what would be criteria for picking the columns to update? is it all but 'id' and 'product' or you rather have list of columns to be updated? please elaborate!

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I'd like to update all the numeric columns, which data type is int or float. (data multiple 10)

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to update all the numeric columns, which data type is int or float. (data multiple 10)

Use below

```
execute immediate (
  select 'update project.dataset.your_table set ' || 
    string_agg(column_name || ' = 10 * ' || column_name, ', ') || 
    ' where true'
  from `project.dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`
  where table_name = 'your_table'
  and data_type in ('INT64', 'FLOAT64')
)
```

your_table before update (`select * from project.dataset.your_table`)

[image]

your_table after update

[image]

> However, I don't expect to update the original table. I only want the result.

```
execute immediate (
select 'select *  replace(' || 
  string_agg('10 * ' || column_name || ' as ' || column_name, ', ') || 
  ') from project.dataset.your_table'
from `project.dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`
where table_name = 'your_table'
and data_type in ('INT64', 'FLOAT64')
)
```

> How could I get the result data?

After above is run - you should click on `VIEW RESULTS`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your advice. However, I don't expect to update the original table. I only want the result.

Comment: got it. see update

Comment: Could I save the result data into a temp table?

Comment: sure. in my answer you have all needed examples to manipulate with result. also you can use update version in my answer for actually updating your temp table, etc. so most importantly - as you question is quite open - don't consider using above answer just as is - rather use it to understand the concept/approach and then modify it so it fits into your exact needs. if still follow up or new question(s) - post it as a new post with all relevant details and we will be happy to further help you  :o)